# UIButton does not override ButtonType property

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, overriding, swift4.2

In subclass of `UIButton` I overrided `ButtonType` property and it was working fine with Swift 4. But with Swift 4.2 (Xcode 10) it can't identify such property from `UIButton`.

Any workaround solution to this issue?

[image]

Comment: note i tried it in xcode 9 , anyway when you write **override var buttonType** the autoComplete will help

Comment: @Sh_Khan - its working fine with Swift 4 but not with swift 4.2 (Xcode 10 only supports Swift 4.2)

Comment: tried below answer in both ??

Comment: Yes, actually `UIButtonType` is converted into `UIButton.ButtonType` in Swift 4.2

Comment: mmm , i see until i try it as currently not setting on xcode 10 machine

Comment: Have you tried clean build?

Comment: @OOPer - Yes, I've tried that

Comment: @Krunal - this may be helpful... (not mine, and I haven't tried it... just found via search):  https://gist.github.com/benasher44/de0a75a4583e5f57853998142e795776

Comment: As far as I tested your code (oh, please show your code in text!), it compiles fine with Xcode 10 GM seed. Sometimes Xcode shows old errors, are you sure your code has no errors other than the one shown?

Comment: @OOPer No, there are yet 412 errors in the code and I'm migrating complete project from Swift 4 to 4.2. May be u r correct. Let me check.

Comment: @Krunal I tried in Xcode 10, and it worked well, no error